# Homebrew installed to home directory - how to link to libs in autoconf?

Tags: homebrew, autoconf

Not sure if this belongs on here or SuperUser, but here goes:

I have Homebrew installed in my $HOME/opt/homebrew dir (I'm pretty religious about isolation for user accounts - yes, I'm one of THOSE people).  In any case, Homebrew doesn't install to /usr/local/.  It works fine because I added Homebrew to the head of my personal path in .bashrc.

I'm now using autoconf.  I'm a C newb.  I have a configure.ac that checks for Apache Portable Runtime.  It does the --install to generate a ./configure just fine.  When I run ./configure, it doesn't find it - probably because it's not looking where Homebrew installed it.

I assume I have to provide arguments to the ./configure script setting the includedir and libdir.  But it doesn't work.  What is the right way to link to these Homebrew libs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity:

In `configure.ac`, I use the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro.  This assumes, of course, that you have `pkg-check` installed, which I do via Homebrew.

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB2, glib-2.0, [], [AC_MSG_FAILURE([glib-2.0 is not installed])])
```

The macro above sets a group of variables for use in the autoconf and automake files prefixed with `GLIB2`.

I use this in the `Makefile.am` thus:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = <myprogram>
<myprogram>_SOURCES = \
        main.c
<myprogram>_CFLAGS = ${GLIB2_CFLAGS}
<myprogram>_LDADD = ${LIBS} ${GLIB2_LIBS}
```

It's really rather straightforward if you use `pkg-config`. You can even package your own libs and install them for use that way, linking them in place with Homebrew.